# Change path for the logfile of PhantomJS in java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs, ghostdriver

I cannot figure out how I can change path for logfile for PhantomJS.
I try with:

```
DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
caps.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
caps.setCapability("takesScreenshot", false);
caps.setCapability(
        PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_GHOSTDRIVER_CLI_ARGS,
            new String[] { "--logfile=/home/ant/Document/phantomjsdriver.log" });
caps.setCapability(
        PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_EXECUTABLE_PATH_PROPERTY,
        path);
```

And also with:

```
ArrayList<String> cliArgsCap = new ArrayList<String>();
cliArgsCap.add("--logfile=/home/ant/Document/phantomjsdriver.log");

DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
caps.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
caps.setCapability("takesScreenshot", false);
caps.setCapability(PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_CLI_ARGS,cliArgsCap);
```

But for now it doesn't work.

Comment: I think the option is `--webdriver-logfile`. Please try.

Answer (score 4):

I struggled a lot to get this working after looking at the code in [PhantomJSDriverService.createDefaultService(...)](https://github.com/detro/ghostdriver/blob/master/binding/java/src/main/java/org/openqa/selenium/phantomjs/PhantomJSDriverService.java#L173) I was able to figure it out.

So here is how I did it, is a little bit hacky but it worked for me...hope this helps:

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
File logfile = new File("ABSOLUTE_PATH_TO_YOUR_LOG_FILE");
String[] phantomArgs = { "--webdriver-loglevel=DEBUG" };
PhantomJSDriverService driverService = new PhantomJSDriverService.Builder()
              .usingPhantomJSExecutable(f)
              .usingAnyFreePort()
              .withProxy(proxy)
              .usingCommandLineArguments(phantomArgs)
              .withLogFile(logfile)
              .build();
PhantomJSDriver driver = new PhantomJSDriver(driverService, capabilities);
```

Comment: Here `usingPhantomJSExecutable(f) `, `f` should be same value with `PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_EXECUTABLE_PATH_PROPERTY` value.

Answer (score 2):

I have been looking for same for some time.

According to [this issue](https://github.com/detro/ghostdriver/issues/239) on GitHub, it is difficult, effectively not possible. There is a workaround mentioned, but you need to provide some of the Ghostdriver source: the `main.js` and all files it imports.

According to [this pull](https://github.com/detro/ghostdriver/pull/438) on GitHub, there is a command line argument `--webdriver-logfile`, and you can see this in the actual log. However, looking through the [PhatomJSDriver source](https://github.com/detro/ghostdriver/blob/master/binding/java/src/main/java/org/openqa/selenium/phantomjs/PhantomJSDriverService.java#L84), accessing the CLI arguments has the same problem: you need the Ghostdriver source.

There is a comment on the [PhantomJS main page](https://github.com/detro/ghostdriver#help-needed) from the maintainer, that he unfortunately no longer has time to work on this.